# How to create XSD Schema with relationship between fields

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, keyref

I am attaching a truncated version of my xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<xs:complexType name="School_ip_details">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Tarun_Name" />
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Tarun_IP" />
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Tarun_Subnet" />

    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="CLASSESS">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Taruns">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Tarun" maxOccurs="127">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Tarun_Name" />
                                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Tarun_Prefix" />
                                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Tarun_Subnet" />
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>



            <xs:element name="Schools">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="School">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="School_IPdetails" type="School_ip_details" />
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>

                <xs:keyref name="TarunRef" refer="TarunKey">
                    <xs:selector xpath="." />
                    <xs:field xpath="./School/School_IPdetails/Tarun_Name" />

                </xs:keyref>
            </xs:element>

        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:key name="TarunKey">
        <xs:selector xpath="./Taruns/Tarun/Tarun_Name" />

        <xs:field xpath="." />
    </xs:key>

    <xs:key name="TarunIPKey">
        <xs:selector xpath="./Taruns/Tarun/Tarun_Prefix" />
        <xs:field xpath="." />
    </xs:key>

</xs:element>
```

Here I want to implement the following scenario. When I refer any value from `CLASSES/Taruns/Tarun/Tarun_Name` to `CLASSES/Scools/School/School_ip_details/Tarun_Name` then value of `CLASSES/Taruns/Tarun/Tarun_Prefix` for that particular `Tarun_Name` should be reflected in `CLASSES/Scools/School/School_ip_details/Tarun_IP`

Please help me for the same

Comment: I used the following code byt no benefit                    <xs:key name="TarunKey">
        <xs:selector xpath="./Taruns/Tarun" />
        <xs:field xpath="Tarun_Name" />
        <xs:field xpath="Tarun_IP" />
    </xs:key>

 <xs:keyref name="TarunRef" refer="TarunKey">
                    <xs:selector xpath="." />
                    <xs:field xpath="./School/School_IPdetails/Tarun_Name" />

   <xs:field xpath="./School/School_IPdetails/Tarun_IP" />


                </xs:keyref>

Answer (score 0):

Look up identity constraints (unique, key, and keyref) in your XSD reference guide.  (You don't have an XSD reference guide?  Get one.)